# Estimating number of connected induced subgraphs of a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, algorithms

In a simple graph, there are $n$ vertices each has exactly $k \ll n$ edges, chosen randomly (details below).  What is the expected value of the number of connected induced subgraphs? Or: what reduction can be made to this problem to make it easier to compute? For example $n=2^{30}$, $k=100$ can be assumed.

---

The graph is constructed in the following way:

1. Generate $n$ vertices.
2. Out of all vertices with $m < k$ edges, pick one randomly (uniform distribution) $v$.
3. Out of all other vertices with less than $k$ edges, pick $k-m$ and connect them with $v$. (At the end, if there are less than $k-m$ connect all of those got left. I think this should not change the result much as $k-m \ll n$)
4. Go back to step 2 until exhausted.

Comment: This doesn't sound so easy even when $k=2$.   I imagine it's not hard to compute the number of connected induced subgraphs of a cycle, but there are so many ways the graph could be a union of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @saulspatz I see. How about rough estimations? lower/upper bounds of expected values?

Comment: I don't have any feel for it at all.  I just tried to see if I could do it for small $k$.  Maybe one could come at it the other way, though.  Choose $m$ vertices.  What is the probability that the subgraph they induce is connected?  If we can do that, we can solve the problem, right?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, so it seems.